# 5% Dividend, 20% Price Drop. Whats the point?

Tags: dividends, yield

This was asked by someone earlier but I did not get the answers.

What's the point of buying dividend stocks for yield  when the stock's price itself may decline so much more?

Here's just one of the very popular high-yield dividend stock that pays ~15% divided and has  fallen 25% since March.

https://stockcharts.com/freecharts/perf.php?amjl

And this happens to every single one.

What's the point of dividend yield when the original investment is losing? What about capital preservation?

The only way this can make sense is that the same stock owner now has 25% more stocks, keeping the net value of his shares the same.

Then, the dividend would be meaningful.

Or the share holder holds out long enough to accumulate enough yield to come above the total drop.

That would mean these stock buys should be timed just like other stocks. But buy them when?

Can someone explain this please.

Answer (score 2):

> And this happens to every single one.

No it does not. A dividend will immediately reduce the price of the stock by the dividend amount, but not all dividend-paying stocks lose more than their dividend.

In fact, if you shift the chart you linked by just a few months (Nov 17 to Aug 18), you'll see that AMJL posted a 35% ***gain*** while paying about 20% in dividends, for a TOTAL return of **55%**.

> The only way this can make sense is, that the same stock owner now has 25% more stocks, keeping the net value of his shares the same.

No, if you had $100 in stock that paid a $5 dividend, the stock would drop to $95 and you'd have $5 in cash. Value is not *created* when a dividend is paid - it is just converted from stock to cash.

The point of a dividend is to let companies return profits to owners without forcing them to sell part of their ownership. With new, growing companies, dividends may not make sense financially, since the company would be better off putting the excess cash towards continued growth, making the company more valuable.  Older, more mature companies sometimes have fewer opportunities for continued growth, and thus pay dividends to offer the owners a better return on the cash in their own investments.

Comment: So contrasting to what these article says, buying company stock just before ex-dividend date can be profitable too in some cases?

Comment: In some cases, sure, but not necessarily because of the dividend. The stock can go up afterwards for a variety of other reasons. There may even be _some_ statistical evidence that stocks go up more often after a dividend payment (i.e. because the P/E ratio is suddenly lower and attracts more value investors). But the dividend itself has zero impact to wealth.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. It's useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

Stock prices go up as well as down. You just happen to be looking at a period when the market performed badly. If prices had gone up 20% you wouldn’t have any doubts, and that’s just as likely. Look at twenty-year price trends, which is long enough to smooth out most market fluctuations. Stocks are certainly riskier than bonds or money in the bank, which is why their average long-term returns are better.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the point of buying Dividend Stocks for yield, when the Stock Price itself may decline so much more.

If that's the case then what's the point of buying ANY stock if you can lose money?

You don't invest in a stock for yield.  Yield is just the conversion of stock value to cash that   is returned to you, lowering your cost basis.  It is not Total Return.

> Here's just one of the very popular high-yield dividend stock that pays ~15% divided. And its fallen 25% since March.

If you bought and held this stock as it dropped 25% from your purchase price, it was a bad investment.  Fortunately, the 15% yield offset some of your loss and you only lost 10%.

> Whats the point of Dividend yield when the original investment is losing? What about capital preservation?

Capital preservation applies to any position regardless of whether it pays a dividend or not. The dividend isn't the problem here.

> The only way this can make sense is, that the same stock owner now has 25% more stocks, keeping the net value of his shares the same.

For that to happen, the dividend would have had to have been 25%.  With reinvestment, the value of the shares would have been somewhere in the vicinity of 'the same'.  However, share price was dropping continuously, so reinvested shares would have lost some money as well and the return would have been a bit less than 'the same'.

> Or, the share holder holds out long enough to accumulate enough yield to come above the total drop.

Buy low, sell high always makes money.  Buy high (with this stock), not so much.

> EDIT:

If you invested $10,000 in AMJL on 12/29/17 at $19.22 (closing price) then you bought 520.29 shares

You received $2.78 in dividends or a total of $1,446

AMJL closed at $11.17 on 12/28/18, down $8.05 for the year (a loss of $4,188).

Of the $8.05 price drop, $2.78 was due to share price reduction by the stock exchanges on the ex-dividend dates and $5.27 was due to poor stock performance.

Total Return = Capital Gain + Interest + Dividend

To keep it simple, let's ignore interest earned if dividends not reinvested

-$2,742 = - $4,188 + $1,446

Or you could achieve the same answer by adjusting the share price loss by the total amount of dividends received and multiply by the number of shares:

(- $8.05 + $2.78) x 520.29 = - $2,742

If the dividends were reinvested, then the  number of shares owned on 12/29/18 would be 610.10
Because share price declined, reinvesting the dividends increased the loss.

610.10 * $11.17 - $10,000 = - $ 3,185

You can verify these numbers at:

https://www.dividendchannel.com/drip-returns-calculator/

Comment: Re "... you only lost 10%", that's only true if the OP sold the stock at that price.  Otherwise, he still has the same shares of stock, the value of which will fluctuate according to a number of factors, many of which have absolutely nothing to do with that particular stock.  In a couple of years the stock could well be back to its original price, or even higher.

Comment: @jamesqf 27 - Let's not conflate other possible events with the current situation.  What happens in the future has nothing to do with the value today. It is a loss  of 10%.  In financial terms, it is called an UNREALIZED LOSS.

Comment: @jamesqf If one goes by the Efficient Market Hypothesis, then they have lost 10%. Furthermore, if one compares the actual universe to a hypothetical one in which they had not bought the stock in March, then to make those two universes comparable they would have to either sell the stock today in the former universe, or buy it today in the latter. Either way, they would be out 10% of the stock price compared to the hypothetical universe. While one could come up with an accounting system in which they have not lost money, those sort of accounting systems are what lead to Enrons.

Comment: @Bob Baerker: If you think it's a loss... Well, just try deducting it on your Schedule D :-)  And you seem to be missing the important point entirely: stocks go up and (alas!) down due to factors that have absolutely nothing to do with their inherent value.  Or haven't you been reading the news these past few weeks?

Comment: @jamesqf Sch D is for realized losses; this one is unrealized (a somewhat artificial tax distinction that leads to complications like the wash-sale rule). Economically they are both losses. Re the "important point", I think you may be intuiting stock prices as a "mean-reverting" process where unrealized losses are likely to be temporary. Rather, the evidence favors a "martingale" process (efficient market) where a stock, no matter how "oversold", is about as likely to decline further as to rebound. Thus, when the value falls 10%, the *expected* value on any future date also falls 10%.

Comment: @BobBaerker Re "lowering your cost basis", it would be good to clarify that this is an *interpretation* that applies if you want to compute your total return *as if* it were a capital gain/loss. It does not actually work this way for tax purposes in the US. Dividends are taxed when received and do not lower the basis for a subsequent capital gain/loss.

Comment: jamesqf - You can play whatever word games you want with the word LOSS means but it doesn't change the fact that your account lost money. By definition, an unrealized LOSS is a loss that results from holding onto an asset after it has decreased in price, rather than selling it and realizing the loss.  In addition, every broker bases its margin calculations on your portfolio value.  If it drops $10k, that's $10k less that they're willing to  lend you on margin.  Gee, I wonder why they're now willing to lend you less?  Could it be because your account LOST money?

Comment: jamesqf - Another consideration: You're on margin with $60k equity and $200k market value (30% margin).  Reg T minimum maintenance requirement (MMR) is 25%. Your account value drops to $180k.  You now have $40k of equity and $180k of MV  with a  22.2% MMR. Your broker sends you a margin call.  You tell your broker, "Leave me alone. I don't need to add money to my account because I didn't sell anything so I didn't LOSE any money!".  Guess what happens?  Your broker sells out some positions. Why? Because you LOST money.  So spare me your silly notion that share price decline isn't a loss.

Comment: @nanoman - Given that the Answer that I wrote was all about calculating  Total Return and that the dividend "is just the conversion of stock value to cash that is returned to you lowering your cost basis",  then I think that the distinction is self evident.